# Webpack CommonsChunkPlugin with async chunks

Tags: webpack

I tried to remove duplication of modules in my webpack chinks useng this article:
https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-bits-getting-the-most-out-of-the-commonschunkplugin-ab389e5f318

I write this code:

```
const config = {
    entry: {
        main: './app/index.ts',
    },
    plugins: [
        new Webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(
            {
                children: true,
                async: true,
                minChunks: ( module, count ) => (
                    // ( count > 1 )
                    module.resource
                    && /\/node_modules\/(?:preact|immutability-helper|small-redux|preact-small-redux)\//.test( module.resource )
                ),
            }
        ),
    ],
    // …
```

And it’s produce this set of chunks:

[image: webpack stats]

As you can see, there is a two copies of my preact-and-stuff bundle (chunk-34d7bcc8f252514ef939 and chunk-a1ef228b5aacb773dff7). It used in chunk-8559295ee847c621304a and in chunk-ac0def536d8c04b6d692 (without CommonsChunkPlugin there is a copy of that modules in each of this chunks). All chunks a loaded asynchronously using `import()` function.

I commented out `count > 1` because it’s counted as one use, but twice in output log (I don’t know why).

Why there is a two copies of required separate chunks and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Explorative attempt: do you still have the 2 duplicate async chunks if you set `minChunks` to 2?

Comment: If I set minChunks to 2 I have a copy of that modules in chunk-8559295ee847c621304a and in chunk-ac0def536d8c04b6d692 (as it was without CommonsChunkPlugin at all). When I add `console.log` with `module.resource` and `count` in `minChunks` function, there is a two lines with required modules with count “1”.